# How do I put text from a form into my Javascript api request?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, fetch-api

Sorry if this is a dumb question,
I have a form in my HTML document and I want to put the text that you submit from the form into my Javascript API call.

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" id="query" name="keyw">
 <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

I need to get the output from this into the [USER TEXT HERE] part

```
 fetch("https://example.com/search?keyw=[USER TEXT HERE]")
 .then((response) => response.json())
```

How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the question's code provides a hint on how to concatenate the text with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript we can create an event listener for onSubmit:

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", fetchSomeAPI);
```

Inside the fetchSomeAPI function it's just a matter of concatenating the user's input and the request:

```
function fetchSomeAPI() {
    fetch(`https://example.com/search?keyw=${document.getElementById("query").value}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the value from the form, you need to listen for a `keypress` event on that `<input />` to make sure that the value is updated every time the user interacts with the input.
Something like: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-quin-g5z54m

Comment: Note that on Stack Overflow we require that code is shared on Stack Overflow in addition to any external sites like Code Sandbox.